# Метод replace python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программа меняет в тексте слово отель на гостиницу. Но возникает ошибка когда слово отель встречается внутри другого слова, например К-*отель*-ники, т.е. программа меняет в этом слове фразу. В итоге получается - Кгостиницаники.

Kак исправить?

Код в упрощенном виде выглядит так:

```
param = "Отель расположен в городе Котельники."
param = param.replace('отель','гостиница')
```

Comment: param = param.replace(r'\bотель\b',гостиница') ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь регулярными выражениями:

```
import re

param = re.sub(r"\bотель\b", "гостиница", param)
param = re.sub(r"\bОтель\b", "Гостиница", param)
```

Результат:

```
In [20]: print(param)
Гостиница расположен в городе Котельники.
```

Answer (score 2):

Не все так просто. Даже после двух проходов вам надо вычитывать и править текст.

```
param = """
    Отель расположен в городе Котельники.
    Этот отель, так себе. Отель как отель.
    Будем искать отель получше.
"""

if "Отель " in param:
    param = param.replace('Отель ','Гостиница ')

if ' отель' in param:
    param = param.replace(' отель',' гостиница')

print(param)

    Гостиница расположен в городе Котельники.
    Этот гостиница, так себе. Гостиница как гостиница.
    Будем искать гостиница получше.
```